# Error when testing semaphore implementation

Tags: go, concurrency, mutex, semaphore, shared-memory

I'm practicing concurrent programming and I've set about implementing several patterns and structures in go. I also added tests in which I use the semaphore as a Mutex in order to increment a shared counter. There is obviously something wrong with my implementation, because after running the test file a couple times, some tests pass yet others fail.
My guess is that somehow, multiple threads get pass the Wait() call without blocking and have concurrent access to the counter variable but I can't figure out why. Any help is appreciated!

semaphore.go

```
package semaphore

import (
    "sync"
)

type Semaphore struct {
    capacity int

    count int
    sync.Mutex
    condition chan bool
}

func (s *Semaphore) Wait() {
    s.Lock()
    defer s.Unlock()

    if s.count == s.capacity {
        s.Unlock()
        <-s.condition
        s.Lock()
    }

    s.count++

}

func (s *Semaphore) Signal() {
    s.Lock()
    defer s.Unlock()

    select {
    case s.condition <- true:
    default:
    }

    s.count--

}

func NewSemaphore(n int) *Semaphore {
    return &Semaphore{count: 0, capacity: n, condition: make(chan bool)}
}
```

semaphore_test.go

```
package semaphore

import (
    "sync"
    "testing"
)

func TestMutexSemaphore(t *testing.T) {

    s := NewSemaphore(1)
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    sharedCounter := 0
    iters := 25
    n := 20

    testfun := func(mutex *Semaphore) {
        defer wg.Done()
        for j := 0; j < iters; j++ {
            s.Wait()
            sharedCounter++
            s.Signal()
        }

    }
    wg.Add(n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        go testfun(s)
    }

    wg.Wait()
    if sharedCounter != iters*n {
        t.Errorf("Bad counter value:%d expected %d", sharedCounter, n*iters)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Wait`, when you wake up and lock, there is no guarantee that the condition still holds. After locking, you should check the condition again:

```
   for s.count == s.capacity {
        s.Unlock()
        <-s.condition
        s.Lock()
    }
```

In `Signal` you should `count--` before waking up others.